# Excel Pivot Table: Open URL with Pivot Table Settings as Parameter

Tags: excel, url, parameters, pivot

I have an Excel file that connects to our customer database. In there, I can break down the number of customers using a Pivot table. For instance, I would see that there are X female customers of age 18-25 who live in the US.

What I'd like to do now, is take this number X, turn it into a link that, when clicked, opens a web browser window to a web application which is also connected to the same customer database and does something with this specific customer segment (i.e. builds a contact file for a newsletter application etc.)

I have no idea how this can be done. I assume that it may be possible to add a custom button to the Excel toolbar which would extract all the current pivot table settings so that I can send them as URL parameters to my web app. Is this possible? If so, how is it done?

Can you help me in the right direction please?
Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

No need to create buttons if you dont have to.

You can use the HYPERLINK() function and concatenate the URL out of text and cell values.

So for example the URL for this page in an excel cell would be:

=HYPERLINK("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/"&A1&"/excel-pivot-table-open-url-with-pivot-table-settings-as-parameter")

Where cell A1 = 18843796

18843796 being the id for this question.  You can do this with as many parameters as you want.

This will create a clickable URL which will automatically open your default browser.

Comment: also, note that `HYPERLINK` has a second parameter where you can set a friendlier name. e.g. `=HYPERLINK("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/"&A1&"/excel-pivot-table-open-url-with-pivot-table-settings-as-parameter","Click me for answer")`

Comment: thank you for your inputs! ok that makes sense. what i don't know yet is how to dynamically build these links. the structure of the pivot table is obviously changing all the time (different combination of rows, columns and values). does it require a macro that updates every time the pivot table is changed and builds new links? or might there be an easier solution to the problem?